# SSE2 code optimization

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics, sse2

I am using SSE2 intrinsics to optimize the bottlenecks of my application and have the following question:

```
ddata = _mm_xor_si128(_mm_xor_si128(
    _mm_sll_epi32(xdata, 0x7u), _mm_srl_epi32(tdata, 0x19u)), xdata);
```

On Microsoft C++ Compiler this won't compile because types `__m128i` and `unsigned int` (passed to `_mm_sll_epi32` instruction) are not interchangeable.

Why is this so and how should I pass the arbitrary `unsigned int` value to `_mm_sll_epi32`?

---

`_m128i` is:

```
typedef union __declspec(intrin_type) _CRT_ALIGN(16) __m128i {
    __int8              m128i_i8[16];
    __int16             m128i_i16[8];
    __int32             m128i_i32[4];    
    __int64             m128i_i64[2];
    unsigned __int8     m128i_u8[16];
    unsigned __int16    m128i_u16[8];
    unsigned __int32    m128i_u32[4];
    unsigned __int64    m128i_u64[2];
} __m128i;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be:

```
ddata = _mm_xor_si128(_mm_xor_si128(
    _mm_slli_epi32(xdata, 0x7), _mm_srli_epi32(tdata, 0x19)), xdata);
```

Note the `i` for "immediate". Without this the shift intrinsics expects a vector as the second argument.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`_mm_slli_epi32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2k3bbtb.aspx) (note the *i*) and likewise [`_mm_srli_epi32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w486zcfa.aspx). It takes an integer argument rather than an `__m128i`.